# Make Flames stick close to the surface instead of rising upwards

Tags: smoke-simulation

[image]I need this for an animation. I tried using a smoke simulator, but the flames rise upwards and that's not what I was aiming for. I want the flames to maintain the vorticity but still stick close to the surface.
Can anyone help me out here?

Update: With the previous answer's help (along with a particle system) I was able to achieve this, however, i want the flames to have a more sharper look to it. Something more akin to the plasma bolt from 'Sorcerer's Apprentice'

Comment: Could you post some images or better a video with effect you want to achieve? Let me know here, in comments if you'll do it.

Comment: @LukeD http://yewnorktimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/2-4.jpg

Comment: @LukeD something like that, where the flames are close to the surface but you can still see it's "individual" flames.

Comment: I've made this: http://imgur.com/a/q4FTK, check if it's ok for you and I can create answer. It's a little bit exaggerated to show it better in GIF. You can control speed, length, opacity and detail of those flames.

Comment: @LukeD it's perfect! Is it possible to add a stutter to the flame? Also could you explain in your answer how you made it (in detail)?

Comment: I'll make one today. What do you mean by stutter?

Comment: @LukeD like make it dim and bright real quick

Comment: did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Final result:

[image: Final]

### Wrapping up:

I'm working with Metric Units (Unit Scale: 1). Result may differ when using other sphere sizes and some tweaking will be needed but I'll explain them later on.

Also, Fire or Plasma is transparent so it will be less visible in bright/white areas, just like fire in real life.

### Objects:

We will need only three of them. *Sphere* as a *Flow object*, *Domain*, and *Force field* which gives us noise to the flame.

1. Start with empty scene and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh* > *UV Sphere*. Keep everything as is.
2. With *Sphere* selected hit <kbd>Space</kbd> and type *Quick Smoke*. Select it.
3. Now we need a *Force field*. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Force Field* > *Turbulence*.

### Domain settings:

Select *Smoke Domain* in the scene or in the *Outliner* and go to *Physics tab*.

**Smoke tab**

[image: 1]

1. **Resolution**. We will leave it now at default value, but for final bake set it to **64**.
2. **Time**. Crank this up to have faster moving flames.
3. **Temp Diff**. It's important one. Set it to 0 so flames will not go in any direction.
4. **Vorticity**. Higher = more noise, lower = smoother flames.

**Smoke Flames tab**

[image: 2]

1. **Speed**. I've set it to 1. It will be connected to *Force field* settings (*strength*).
2. **Smoke**. Set it to 0. We don't need any smoke.
3. **Vorticity**. Same as *Vorticity* in *Smoke tab*.

**Smoke Adaptive Domain and Smoke High Resolution tab**

[image: 3]

1. Check *Smoke Adaptive Domain*.
2. In *Smoke High Resolution* set it to *2 Divisions*.
3. Lower *Noise Method* to 1. You can try and play with it. Low setting will give smooth flames and really high make them raving.

### Sphere (Smoke Flow) settings:

Select our *Sphere*, you should see settings right away in the same place where *Domain* was.

**Smoke tab**

[image: 4]

1. Change *Flow type* to *Fire*.
2. *Flow rate* is really fun to play with setting. Low value gives us really gentle flames, and high values will create total destruction.

### Force field settings:

Select *Force field* (or *Field* in *Outliner*) and go to *Physics tab* (same as other objects).

[image: 5]

1. **Strength**. Set it to 35 or lower if you want shorter flames.

**Note: If you set it to low value, flame will be shorter but also slower. Consider changing in *Domain settings Time scale* and *Flame speed*.**

2. **Noise**. Max it out. You can keyframe *Seed* to have even more noise.

### Materials:

We will need materials for our flame - this will be *Domain*, and for *Sphere*, to simply hide it.

### Domain or Flame/Plasma material

[image: 6]

1. Select *Smoke Domain* and go to *Node Editor*.
2. Delete everything there besides *Material Output*.
3. Add *Attribute node*. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Input* > *Attribute* and type in it *flame*.
4. Add *Color Ramp*. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Converter* > *Color Ramp*. Add there couple of colors you want, place as you want but remember to set last one (right one) to Alpha 0 and set color to it as well.
5. Add *Emission Shader*. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Shader* > *Emission*.
6. Connect everything as in picture above.

### Sphere or Flow material

Just add *Transparent BSDF* to it. Nothing more.

### Final thoughts:

Now you can play or bake (under *Domain* > *Smoke cache* settings) scene. Remember to set for final render *Resolution* to 64, and to have dark background.

Save a lot. I mean it. **A lot**.

Setup is really flexible, so don't afraid to test other settings.

I didn't achieve good stutter or flicker effect. The only thing I've come up was adding *Brightness/Contrast node* between *Attribute* and *Emission* and keyframing *Brightness* value, but this is horribly slow process. Maybe *F-curves* will help but I'm not good in animation.

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: @Tejas If you can thank me for my hard work for you, consider upvoting and accepting my answer, and if something is wrong, please tell me what it is so I can improve my answer.

Comment: It's perfect, mate.. thanks a ton and sorry for the late reply, was busy with another project i'm running... Also i have another question, is it possible to make this look like the "flames" from a welding torch?

Comment: @Tejas You mean colors or flame speed?

Comment: speed and shape

Comment: @Tejas I don't think it's possible. Flame from welding torch is strictly one directional so it can have such a velocity thus shape. In this case flames goes in every direction and are much more dynamic. If we will reproduce welding torch flames on sphere it will look like... Spiked ball.

Comment: @Tejas reduce Vorticity (both) to 0 and Wevelenght to 0, try reducing Noise in Force Field. It will give much smoother flames. Also Increase Speed and Time scale.

Comment: ok, i see.. wait, where's wavelength?

Comment: @Tejas My mistake :) Smoke High Resolution > Noise Method > Strenght