# Plasma Flare effect

Tags: particles, effects

Is there a way to achieve a plasma effect as found in Halo?[image: plasma]

I want to create the blue plasma/flame effect not as an animation but just an image.

Comment: Please show some of your work with Particles and Turbulence.  Searchable at BSE.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71461/make-flames-stick-close-to-the-surface-instead-of-rising-upwards/71662#71662 This could probably be duplicate, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

- Cycles Render or Blender Render or Other Renderer can be selected.
- Consider particles with turbulence.
- For quick rendering enhance and color and blur in the Blender Compositor. Cycles not necessary.

  - Create transparent texture as many games do
  - Use ordinary light sources rather than particle light sources
- For enhanced realism or different style. Point density with particle system with Cycles for computational efficiency.
- Particles as light sources either in Cycles or Blender Render.
- Search here at BSE for particles and turbulence
- The goal here is to give you high level direction.  No tutorial is provided here.  You can also search on the famous video website for particles and turbulence.  Rhymes with NooNoob.