# How to create a hyperspace window effect?

Tags: animation, effects, procedural, texture-coordinates

I would like to create the hyperspace window from the Stargate series. I tried dynamic paint, many different textures (mostly combining gradient and noise), different texture coordinates, displacement modifiers, shape keys, pretty much everything, but I always got a lame version of it. So could anyone give me some tips how should I do it? As simple as possible.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Search for Volumetric objects. this looks the best but is not free https://blendermarket.com/products/30-awesome-procedural-volumetric-spheres--bonus-course-with-2-projects then there are https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15737/how-to-create-an-sci-fi-plasma-energetic-force-field-material-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121121/plasma-flare-effect